# Get lat and lon for each point in polygon - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, maps

I found an answer for how to get the latitude and longitude for each point of the polygon here:

[Polygon Drawing and Getting Coordinates with Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072059/polygon-drawing-and-getting-coordinates-with-google-map-api-v3/22696201#22696201)

This appeared to work when I implemented it, however is no longer working, and I get the error:

"Error: TypeError: polygon.overlay.latLngs.b is undefined"

This is my code:

```
function polygonPoints(polygon) {
    var polygonPointsArray = [];

    $.each(polygon.overlay.latLngs.b[0].b, function(key, latlng){
            var lat = latlng.d;
            var lon = latlng.e;

            polygonPointsArray.push(lat+' '+lon); //do something with the coordinates
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That failed because polygon internal structure changed which happens from time to time.

How to get latitude and longitude of polygon points is described in this [google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays).

Comment: when did they change this?

Thanks though, I figured it out using that example.

Comment: I don't know exactly but it is not so uncommon so better to use official API calls to get values.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well - the quick fix for me was to change

```
$.each(polygon.overlay.latLngs.b[0].b, function(key, latlng){
```

to

```
$.each(polygon.overlay.latLngs.j[0].j, function(key, latlng){
```