# How to draw a Polygon (Rectangle) on Google Maps with defined distance (Meters) from user's input points

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This Android app will be used to help define borders or city limits etc.  The user will draw a rectangle defining the borders on the Google map, and the app will increase the the length and width of the rectangle the by the predefined amount of meters.

I know there is a method in the API that calculates distance between coordinates, but here I am starting with meters and want to find the coordinates of the new (to be drawn) larger polygon.  Does anyone know how I would make this calculation?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)

```
// The distance you want to increase your square (in meters)
double distance = 104.52;

// A List of LatLng defining your user's input
// (Two latLng define a square)
List<LatLng> positions = new ArrayList<>();
positions.add(new LatLng(40.22861, -3.95567));
positions.add(new LatLng(40.22884, -3.95342));

// Create a LatLngBounds.Builder and include your positions
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (LatLng position : positions) {
    builder.include(position);
}

// Calculate the bounds of the initial positions
LatLngBounds initialBounds = builder.build();

// Increase the bounds by the given distance
// Notice the distance * Math.sqrt(2) to increase the bounds in the directions of northeast and southwest (45 and 225 degrees respectively)
LatLng targetNorteast = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(initialBounds.northeast, distance * Math.sqrt(2), 45);
LatLng targetSouthwest = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(initialBounds.southwest, distance * Math.sqrt(2), 225);

// Add the new positions to the bounds
builder.include(targetNorteast);
builder.include(targetSouthwest);

// Calculate the bounds of the final positions
LatLngBounds finalBounds = builder.build();
```

You can draw the bounds to see if everything is working using the following function:

```
private void drawBounds (LatLngBounds bounds, int color) {
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions =  new PolygonOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.southwest.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.southwest.latitude, bounds.southwest.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.southwest.longitude))
            .strokeColor(color);

    mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
}
```

For example:

```
drawBounds (initialBounds, Color.BLUE);
drawBounds (finalBounds, Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

In getting the coordinates of a polygon you can check this [`codepen`](http://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/ujdgK) in how to do that. Your output here will be set of coordinates(Lat and Lng). Since you want to get the coordinates in meter you can use [spherical geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Geometry) in calculating the distance.

To compute this distance, call [computeDistanceBetween(),](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) passing it two LatLng objects.
 Distance results are expressed in meters.

Check also this SO questions for more information.

[SO ticket 7997627](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997627/google-maps-how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-point-in-metre)

[SO ticket 5072059](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072059/polygon-drawing-and-getting-coordinates-with-google-map-api-v3/)